# Изменить ключ подписи play console

Tags: android-studio, google-play-console

Подписал по ошибке приложение новым ключом, старый найти не могу. Прила на макете уже 2 года. Вот решил обновить ее и выкатить новую версию, но естественно с новым ключом подписи это сделать невозможно. Что делать? Пересоздавать приложение нет желания особо...

Comment: Если старого ключа нет и вы подписываете сами, а не через гугл - ничего не сделать. Только новое приложение создавать

Comment: Это я уже понял ))) спасибо